# Cosmos DB trigger that writes data to another Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to implement a trigger that will take all incoming changes and write them to my other Cosmos DB.

[image]

I'm aware of Change Feed and how it works, but currently, I'm looking for the approach to write changes with container triggers.
What I can't find is how can I create a connection to another database. Is it even possible inside a containers triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers in Cosmos DB are scoped to a single logical partition the same as stored procedures. Also, triggers must be called manually.

To copy data from one container to another you should use Change Feed.

Comment: Hey @Mark Brown, just confirming whether the statement where the triggers in cosmos db are scoped to a logical partition is correct? I can't seem to find this in the docs - although here it says "Like stored procedures, triggers live within the confines of a *collection*, thus confining the application logic to the *collection.*" which seems like an important difference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/triggers

Comment: Update to my comment above: I did a simple test, and it looks like it is indeed *scoped to the logical partition*